# Is there any MacOS SwiftUI alternatives to UIKit's UIGraphicsBeginImageContext/UIGraphicsEndImageContext?

Tags: macos, uikit

I need to merge multiple images into one, so I needed UIKit's UIGraphicsBeginImageContext. But macOS apps doesn't allow importing UIKit. Is there any alternatives I can use to merge multiple images to one?

I also need to save the result image, if that's important.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192782/uigraphicsbeginimagecontextwithoptions-analog-in-macos

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223739/ios-to-mac-graphiccontext-explanation-conversion